# MongoDB aggregate different collections

Tags: mongodb

i've been trying to do this aggregation since yesterday with no luck, hope you guys can give me some ideas. A little background, I have 2 collections, one for results and another for questions. Results is basically where people solve questions, so it can have 1 question or up to 99 if i'm not mistaken. This is the simplified schema:

```
Results Schema:
_id: ObjectId("6010664ac5c4f77f26f5d005")
questions: [
  {
    _id: ObjectId("5d2627c94bb703bfcc910763"),
    correct: false
  },
  {
    _id: ObjectId("5d2627c94bb703bfcc910764"),
    correct: true
  },
  {
    _id: ObjectId("5d2627c94bb703bfcc910765"),
    correct: true
  }
]
```

So, on this specific object, the user answered 3 questions and got 2 of them correct.

```
Questions Schema:
_id: ObjectId("5d2627c94bb703bfcc910763")
```

What i'm struggling to do is: for each element in all the questions schema, I have to check if the question was answered - i.e (check if there's an _id of questions array == _id on the Questions Schema, yes there can be multiple questions with the same _id as Questions Schema, but Questions Schema _id is unique). If that question was answered, I need to check if correct = true, if so, I add it to a correctAnswer variable, if not, wrongAnswer.

I've tried many things so far with conditions, group to get the $sum of correct and wrong answers, lookup to join both collections but so far, I can't even get to show just the aggregation result.

One of the things I tried (i was trying to do baby steps first) but as mentioned before, couldn't even get the result printed.

```
Result.aggregate([
    $lookup: {
      from: 'question',
      localField: 'questions._id',
      foreignField: '_id',
      as: 'same'
    },
```

But this gets me both collections combined, and 'same' comes as empty array, tried using match with also no luck.
I also did a $project to just get the information I wanted

```
$project: {
  _id: 0,
  questions: {
  _id: 1,
  correct: 1
  }
},
```

Tried using $group:
$group: {
_id: "$_id",
$cond: {if: {"$correct": { $eq: true}}, then: {testField: {$sum: 1}}, else: {testField: 0}}
}
And as I said, i was just trying to do baby steps so it the testField was beeing manually set, also tried many other things from stackoverflow.
Would appreciate the help and sorry for the very long text, just wanted to put in some examples that I did and tried.

**TLDR**: Need to find a `question` from the `Results Schema` where `_id` matches an `_id` from the `Questions Schema`, if there is, check if `correct: true` or `correct: false`. Update `Questions Schema` accordingly with how many were correct and how many were wrong for each `question` from `Questions Schema`.
Example: `newField: {correctAnswer: 4, wrongAnswer: 3}` so in this case, there were 7 questions from the `Result schema` `question` array that matched an `_id` from `Question Schema`, 4 had `correct: true` and 3 had `correct: false`. Then it goes on like this for the rest of `Question Schema`

Comment: Could you clarify what you are looking for?  Is it, for each `question`, you want to return two arrays, one array with `_id` from `answer` of `"correct": true` answers, and another array with `_id` from `answer` of `"correct": false` answers?

Comment: Yeah, sorry. I didn't say it in the text, but I wanted to update the ```Questions Schema``` to add a property saying how many questions were correct and how many were wrong, basically add a new field ```newField: {correctAnswers: 2, wrongAnswers: 5}```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a scenario where `"$lookup"` can't be used because the `Question` collection is in a different database, the `Result` collection may be used to generate output documents to update the `Question` collection.

Here's one way to do it.

```js
db.Result.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": "$questions"
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$questions._id",
      "correct": {
        "$push": "$questions.correct"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "newField": {
        "correctAnswers": {
          "$size": {
            "$filter": {
              "input": "$correct",
              "as": "bool",
              "cond": "$$bool"
            }
          }
        },
        "wrongAnswers": {
          "$size": {
            "$filter": {
              "input": "$correct",
              "as": "bool",
              "cond": { "$not": "$$bool" }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/8-yPjzeah_c).

Comment: I can't upvote, so I'll just comment. It worked perfectly, thank you so so much for your time! I was stuck trying to do that for 1 week

Comment: Glad it worked!  You could "accept" the answer if it meets your needs.  BTW, I have my own MongoDB queries that I need to develop, but my working knowledge of MongoDB has been greatly expanded by trying to solve problems presented here on SO.  Thanks for the challenge!

Comment: Thats great to hear. I also wanted to know how I would do if I wanted to get let's say, the last 7 days of those answers based on the ```createdAt``` field, that is outside of the questions array, on the same nest as of ```_id```. I was trying to just project the ```createdAt``` field but didn't get any luck doing that :(

Comment: @DAVIFONSECA You could use `"$match"` as a first stage in the pipeline with your conditions.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a way to `"$lookup"` and `update` at the same time.  There's probably a better way to do this, but the aggregation pipeline below creates the documents that could be used in a subsequent `update`.  The pipeline correctly counts repeat questions by a single `Result` `_id`, in case someone keeps trying a question until they get it right.  One possible issue is that if a question has no `Result` answers, then no `"newField": { "correctAnswers": 0, "wrongAnswers": 0 }` document is created.

```js
db.Question.aggregate([
  {
    // lookup documents in Result that match _id
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "Result",
      "localField": "_id",
      "foreignField": "questions._id",
      "as": "results"
    }
  },
  {
    // unwind everything
    "$unwind": "$results"
  },
  {
    // more of everything
    "$unwind": "$results.questions"
  },
  {
    // only keep answers that match question
    "$match": {
      "$expr": { "$eq": [ "$_id", "$results.questions._id" ] }
    }
  },
  {
    // reassemble and count correct/wrong answers
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$_id",
      "correct": {
        "$sum": {
          "$cond": [ { "$eq": [ "$results.questions.correct", true ] }, 1, 0 ]
        }
      },
      "wrong": {
        "$sum": {
          "$cond": [ { "$eq": [ "$results.questions.correct", false ] }, 1, 0 ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    // project what you want as output
    "$project": {
      newField: {
        correctAnswers: "$correct",
        wrongAnswers: "$wrong"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/NUufcFi9wGL).

Comment: I tried in my code but It's not working, but I have an idea of what might be. My Result collection is on another db, different from Question. Would lookup still be possible in this case? Thank you so so much for your reply!

Comment: Unfortunately, [`"$lookup"` only works with an "unsharded collection in the same database"](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#mongodb-pipeline-pipe.-lookup).  Can you move the collection to the same database?  If not, you may be stuck doing the lookup from the app/programming side.  Another option might be to "pretend" the `Question` collection doesn't exist but are represented by the `Result` `"questions._id"`.  The same output documents could be generated.  I'll submit another answer with that approach when time allows.